# Create an instance of a class and initialize all its fields

Tags: java, reflection, jaxb

I want to create an instance of a class, but I also need to initialize also all its fields recursively.

The code you see related do the objectFactory is because some of this classes could be JAXB classes, so for every package there is an ObjectFactory with methods like createJaxbObject(....).

EDITED:

My final solutions is this one:

```
public Object getInstance(Class<?> instanceClass, Boolean simple,
        String jaxbName) {

    Object instance = null;
    try {
        if (instanceClass.isPrimitive())
            return primitiveValues.get(instanceClass.getName());
        if (List.class.isAssignableFrom(instanceClass))
            return new ArrayList();
        else if (instanceClass.isEnum())
            return instanceClass.getEnumConstants()[0];
        else if (instanceClass.isArray())
            return java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(instanceClass, 1);
        else if (BigInteger.class.isAssignableFrom(instanceClass))
            return new BigInteger("0");
        else if (instanceClass.equals(String.class))
            return "";
        else if (instanceClass.equals(Boolean.class))
            return false;
        else if (instanceClass.equals(EntityObjectStringType.class))
            return new EntityObjectStringType();
        else if (JAXBElement.class.isAssignableFrom(instanceClass)) {
            try {
                Method m = null;
                Class<?> objFactoryClass = null;
                Iterator<String> it = EditorServlet.objectFactories
                        .iterator();
                Object of = null;
                while (it.hasNext()) {
                    objFactoryClass = Class.forName(it.next());
                    of = objFactoryClass.getConstructor().newInstance();
                    m = getMethodFromObjectFactory(objFactoryClass,
                            jaxbName);
                    if (m != null)
                        if (m.getParameterTypes().length > 0)
                            break;
                }
                Object jaxbElement = getInstance(m.getParameterTypes()[0],
                        m.getParameterTypes()[0].getSimpleName());
                return m.invoke(of, jaxbElement);

            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                logger.error("JAXB NoSuchMethodException");
            }
        } else
            try {
                logger.info("Costruttori per " + instanceClass.getName()
                        + " " + instanceClass.getConstructors().length);
                instance = instanceClass.getConstructor().newInstance();
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException noSuchMethodException) {
                logger.error("getConstructors NoSuchMethodException");
            }
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        logger.error("IllegalArgumentException " + instanceClass.getName());
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        logger.error("SecurityException " + instanceClass.getName());
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        logger.error("InstantiationException " + instanceClass.getName()
                + " " + instanceClass.isPrimitive());
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        logger.error("IllegalAccessException " + instanceClass.getName());
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        logger.error("InvocationTargetException " + instanceClass.getName());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        logger.error("ClassNotFoundException " + instanceClass.getName());
    }
    if (!simple) {
        for (Field field : instanceClass.getDeclaredFields()) {
            try {
                Object fieldInstance = getInstance(field.getType(),
                        field.getName());
                field.setAccessible(true);
                field.set(instance, fieldInstance);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                logger.error("IllegalArgumentException "
                        + instanceClass.getName());
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                logger.error("IllegalAccessException "
                        + instanceClass.getName());
            }
        }
    }

    return instance;
}
```

Comment: "The method never ends" - did you try any debugging to find out where does it get stuck?

Comment: yes it seems that the problem is inside the for of the first if (ex: it cannot create an instance of BigInteger)

Comment: Because your recursion has no break point.

Answer (score 1):

If I could hazard a guess, you're calling your method recursively in your `NoSuchMethodException` catch.

```
Object of = getInstance(objFactoryClass);
```

If your recursive call keeps on not finding the method on:

```
Method m = getMethodFromObjectFactory(objFactoryClass, c);
```

... the method will call itself again, which should end with a `StackOverflowError` at some point.

Comment: probably yes, but the problems is that I don't know how to try before the usual constructor, and after that try with the ObjectFactory. Because the key is to understand if the class is a JAXBElement, I tried with the usual JAXBElement.class.isAssignableFrom(c) but it's not working

Answer (score 1):

#### Your recursion has no break point

Try to stop recursion where the class is primary type:

```
    if (List.class.isAssignableFrom(c))
        instance = new ArrayList();
    else if (c.isEnum())
        return c.getEnumConstants()[0]; //avoid stackoverflow error
    else if(c.isPrimitive()) {
        instance = c.getConstructor().newInstance();
        // use must stop here
        return instance;
    } else{
        instance = c.getConstructor().newInstance();
    }
```

The `isPrimitive` will judge whether the `class` is primary type(int ,Integer,shor,Short,String...)

Comment: thanks, I tried and I have exception with this class: bitsPerDigit [J. I've also updated the code in my question

Comment: try to add c.isArray() to you else if condition. And create an array of the given type.

Comment: done, and I also put an if for the BigInteger class, now it gives other exception but it finish the execution. (I updated the question)

Comment: oh~, some class did not have a public default constructor, so you need to access the default constructor by reflection.

Comment: If the class is an interface, you need to assign a default subtype for instance, otherwise, it can not be instanced. eg: java.util.List assign to java.util.ArrayList for instance.